# multipart form-data with text and image

Tags: php, forms, multipartform-data

I have a form in which the user has to input some text and an image.

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['name']))
 {
   echo "name";
   if(isset($_FILES['image']))
     echo "image";
 }
 echo <<<F
   <form method="post" action="test.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="text" name="name">
   <input type="file" name="image">
   </form>
 F;
?>
```

In this sample, even if i don't choose any image, the text "image" gets echoed. What modifications should i make such that "image" is only echoed when i select an image, if not, the rest of the form gets submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Change with

```
 if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) echo "image";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it like this:

```
if (isset($_FILES['image']) && $_FILES['image']['error'] == 0)
```

**Error** field contains a PHP error code, it equals to 4 when no file was uploaded.

You can find more information here: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php